# Nunit 3.10 stacktrace is not as detailed as 3.9

Tags: nunit

I'm using Nunit with Selenium C# and noticed the upgrade of Nunit to 3.10 has changed the stacktrace output. An example is...

3.9.0

```
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.DefaultWait`1.ThrowTimeoutException(String 
exceptionMessage, Exception lastException)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.DefaultWait`1.Until[TResult](Func`2 condition)
at ObservatoryAutomationFramework.SeleniumGetMethods.WaitForElementClickable(IWebDriver driver, IWebElement element, Int32 timeoutInSeconds, String frame, String frameType, String frameNumber) in C:\...\ActionMethods\SeleniumGetMethods.cs:line 441
at ObservatoryAutomationTests.UserScenarios_17.Test_17_ContractV2() in C:\...\Scenario17.cs:line 108
--NoSuchElementException
at SeleniumExtras.PageObjects.DefaultElementLocator.LocateElement(IEnumerable`1 bys)
at SeleniumExtras.PageObjects.WebElementProxy.get_Element()
at SeleniumExtras.PageObjects.WebElementProxy.Invoke(IMessage msg)
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
at OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement.get_Displayed()
at SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.<>c__DisplayClass20_0.b__0(IWebDriver driver)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.DefaultWait`1.Until[TResult](Func`2 condition)
--TearDown
at NUnit.Framework.Assert.ReportFailure(String message)
at NUnit.Framework.Assert.Fail(String message, Object[] args)
at NUnit.Framework.Assert.Fail(String message)
at ObservatoryAutomationTests.UserScenarios_17.TestTeardown() in C:\...\Scenario17.cs:line 201
```

3.10.0

```
at ObservatoryAutomationTests.UserScenarios_17.TestTeardown() in C:\...\Scenario17.cs:line 201

--TearDown
at NUnit.Framework.Assert.ReportFailure(String message) in C:\src\nunit\nunit\src\NUnitFramework\framework\Assert.cs:line 408
at NUnit.Framework.Assert.Fail(String message, Object[] args) in C:\src\nunit\nunit\src\NUnitFramework\framework\Assert.cs:line 155
at NUnit.Framework.Assert.Fail(String message) in C:\src\nunit\nunit\src\NUnitFramework\framework\Assert.cs:line 165
at ObservatoryAutomationTests.UserScenarios_17.TestTeardown() in C:\...\Scenario17.cs:line 201
```

Is there some kind of command to get the same level of output I had in 3.9 without downgrading back to 3.9?

Answer (score 0):

The two stack traces differ because the first shows two errors, the second only one.

The first trace indicates that an error occured in your test followed by another in your teardown. The second only shows a teardown error occuring at the point in time where NUnit is attempting to report a failure.

Whatever you are doing in teardown to cause the error (you could post code here for advice) should be fixed first. It's hard to figure out what's wrong if NUnit is not able to report the error.

Comment: Thanks. The two traces are from the exact same test under debug, forcing it to fail. So the failure in the test shown under 3.9 should also be reported in 3.10 but for some reason isn't. I've repeated this a number of times and always the same outcome under both version of Nunit.

Comment: Line 408 of Assert.cs is where NUnit is reporting the failure and throws an exception. It looks to me like something has gone wrong in the trimming of the stack, which we do so that you don't get a bunch of NUnit stuff in the output. I suggest filing a bug report.